# SwiftUI Preview crash with await async iOS15 if returns a struct with UUID

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios15

I reduced to very simple code.
If the struct has a `Int` is working, if there is an `UUID` the preview is crashing  (it's working if I run on the simulator or real device)

**Tested with
iOS 15
Xcode 13.1 and beta 13.2**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct MyStruct: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID() //with Int is ok
    var str: String
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @State private var myStruct: MyStruct = MyStruct(str: "struct1-init")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myStruct.str)
                .onAppear(perform: doSometingStruct)
        }
    }
    
    private func doSometingStruct() {
        Task {
            let get = await getAsyncStruct()
            myStruct = get
        }
    }
    
    private func getAsyncStruct() async -> MyStruct {
        let str = MyStruct(str: "struct1-done")
        return str
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

Comment: `var id: String = UUID().uuidString` use this

Comment: @ChanOnly123 thanks, but I don't think it's a good idea to change all my code just to prevent preview crash

Comment: What error message is the preview crash giving you?  I am using UUID() in my previews on iOS 15 without issue.

Comment: I’m having the same issue but not even a UUID, just a struct made up of multiple other structs.  Happens when I add the async keyword to the function but a similar function that returns a string also with the async works fine.  The error in the back trace is `await resume partial function for closure #2`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug of xcode to preview Views with async-code... Try to test with commented Task:

```
private func doSometingStruct() {
        //Task {
        //    let get = await getAsyncStruct()
        //    myStruct = get
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t feel “right”, but was able to get around the issue by not having the async function return anything and store the struct in a global variable that can be gotten from the calling function.  Feels all sorts of wrong but it does work to fix the crash.  If someone has a better solution, I’d love to know!

Answer (score 0):

I got around this (for anyone else still experiencing this issue) by forcing the async function to sleep for a short time before returning the result on previews only.

Here's an example:

```
private func getAsyncStruct() async -> MyStruct {
    let str = MyStruct(str: "struct1-done")
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    return str
}
```

Note that, in order to make sure you're not doing this in your production code and only for previews, I'll mock out `getAsyncStruct` into a dependency where the above is passed in for previews and a different implementation is passed in for live.

For instance,

```
private func getAsyncStruct() async -> MyStruct {
    viewModel.getAsyncStrut()
}
```

And then a different `viewModel` with the implementation above can be passed into the preview.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be fixed in Xcode 14.0